# How To Edit File On Remote Local Network Computer, But Not On Internet:

Tags: linux, sftp

I have a GPU cluster which I can access by ssh-ing into an intermediate computer, and then ssh-ing into the cluster. (The intermediate computer resides on the same network as the cluster, but the cluster is not connected to the Internet)

I prefer not to use in-terminal editors like vim and would also like to avoid copying files to the intermediate computer and then onto the cluster, so I am looking for a way to remotely edit files on the cluster with an IDE on my local computer.

If I were directly ssh-ed into the cluster, I could use SFTP to edit the files on the cluster.

However, there is an intermediate computer. Is there someway I can use SFTP or a similar technology to achieve my goal?

Thanks for any help and let me know if I can be more clear.

Comment: I'm not sure it is worth the trouble. Alternatively, use some distributed version control system (i.e. `git`) to manage such files (both on your local laptop and on the remote cluster).

Comment: I don't think git would help me here. I can only access the cluster through the intermediate computer and I can't install software on the intermediate computer. :/. I do appreciate the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for an SFTP connection to your `cluster` through a SSH connection to your `gateway` - so for SSH tunneling.
Use on your local machine

```
ssh gateway -L localPort:cluster:portToCluster -l user -p portToGateway
```

to open a SSH tunnel to your `cluster`. For localPort use any free port on your local machine (e.g. 2222), portToCluster is the port you usually use for connecting to your `cluster` from the `gateway` (standard port is 22) and portToGateway is the port you use for connecting to the `gateway` from your local machine.

Now you can access the `cluster` simply using a SFTP connection to localhost:2222

Your SSH tunnel must be open as long as you wish to use this SFTP connection. So keep your SSH connection running.

Comment: This worked very well for me. Thank you! Simple solution for a strange scenario!

Comment: Oops. I thought I did. I always make sure to give credit where it is deserved, but apparently I only upvoted instead of accepting. Fixed!